# How do I get this React method to return a statement/variable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is a snippet from JobInfoPage.js file,

```
import findMonthsTillSession from '../components/utility.js';

class JobInfoPage extends Component {
    render() {
            <div>The nearest hiring session is in: { findMonthsTillSession() } See you then!</div>
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:
`Attempted import error: '../components/utility.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'findMonthsTillSession').`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help! I guess since I exported *without* default, I had to put curly braces on the import, like so:

```
import { findMonthsTillSession } from '../components/utility.js';
```

Now comes the hard part of calculating the months!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors in your question, 
(1) `No return() in JobInfoPage.js` file 
(2) `Function is not imported with function name.`
In `JobInfoPage.js`

```
import findMonthsTillSession from '../components/utility.js';

class JobInfoPage extends Component {
    render() {
       return(
       <div>
            The nearest hiring session is in: { findMonthsTillSession() } See you then!
       </div>
       )
    }
}
```

Add `import React from 'react';` in Utility.js if you have not added.

Also read [hackernoon export import cheatsheet](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f).

Comment: Runs, but nothing prints out, like in the edit I made to the post. I will definitely read the cheatsheet though, I'm not good at exporting and importing lol

Comment: @HelanaBrock i have updated the answer please check

Comment: ```import React, { useState } from 'react';``` is at the top, is that importing React?

Comment: @HelanaBrock There are 2 errors in your question, (1) `No return() in JobInfoPage.js` file (2) `Function is not imported with function name.` Same is updated in this answer.

Comment: It actually didn't solve my problem, I was thanking because I needed to fix those errors, either way I figured it out! I'll post my own answer but I can upvote if it'll let me because of your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to import React into your utility.js

```
import React from 'react';

export function FindMonthsTillSession() {
    return <p> 5 months </p>;
}
```

then you import your utility like the following:

```
import FindMonthsTillSession from '../components/utility
```

Comment: I'll change my question and add this if this is the case, but ```import React, { useState } from 'react';``` is at the top of the "utility.js" file, is that importing React or just useState?

Comment: If you use `useState` you need to import it, but in your case, you want to return an your element tag, I think React is enough.

Comment: A your element tag? Also, in the question, I only posted code relevant to my problem, there is a lot more and im sure its using useState

Comment: You need to export your function as you can see in the code above. Use uppercase to the first letter of your function `FindMonthsTillSession` otherwise it will cause the error you mentionned. 
It's not the use state which cause your bug